# Trying to put a string into an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I've created a very simple code but it doesn't work! I just want to create an array which will contain strings. However these strings *must* be put without the character-character method. In other words:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char wstr[20][10];         
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
            wstr[i]='BA';
    return 0;
}
```

but the compiler shows me a warning and an error:

```
[Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[10]' from type 'int'
[Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

What should I do?

Comment: `strcpy(wstr[i], "BA");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<20;i++)
            strcpy(wstr[i], "BA");
```

Single quotes are for single characters; string literals use double quotes. 
The `strcpy()` call ensures that you will be able to modify the values later,
since modifying the string literal itself is undefined behavior.